# How can I solve "Error: Cannot find module '@babel/parser' " after 'vue create' command?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, node.js, npm

I am new to Vue.js. I tried to create new projet according to tutorials and official Vue/CLI manual.

1) First I ran the command `npm install @vue/cli -g`.

2) Then I ran the command `vue create my-project`.

I am getting this error:

```
$ vue create my-project
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/parser'
Require stack:
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\jscodeshift\parser\babel5Compat.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\jscodeshift\src\getParser.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\jscodeshift\src\core.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\jscodeshift\index.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\util\runCodemod.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\GeneratorAPI.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\Generator.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\Creator.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\create.js
-{My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> ({My user folder}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\jscodeshift\parser\babel5Compat.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\node_modules\\jscodeshift\\parser\\babel5Compat.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\node_modules\\jscodeshift\\src\\getParser.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\node_modules\\jscodeshift\\src\\core.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\node_modules\\jscodeshift\\index.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\util\\runCodemod.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\GeneratorAPI.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\Generator.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\Creator.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\create.js',
    '{My user folder}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\bin\\vue.js'
  ]
}
```

I tried to install latest @vue/cli version (4.0.5) and also older version (3.12.0). I'm using Windows 10 Home with installed Node (12.13.0) and NPM (6.12.0).

**How can I solve this error?**

Comment: Ensure you are using the latest versions.

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest versions.